# Why is vscode highlighting my type annotations?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm building a simple components with TS/React. I'm finding VSCode is highlighting my type annotations.

[image: A typescript component with highlighted type annotations]

In the problems panel I see:

[image: Type annotation information]

They are neither warnings nor errors but they are causing a lot of visual noise.

Why am I seeing these? How do I make them go away?

Comment: You are using the total-typescript VSCode extension

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mattpocock.ts-error-translator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Geoffrey and Nicholas, you are using  [total-typescript](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mattpocock.ts-error-translator) VS Code extension, which displays hints for you to learn Typescript. You can hide these hints by marking them as learned.

Comment: I didn't realise I had this extension installed. Thanks